# Can't update JTable's info

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I create the JTable with data contained in an ArrayList and then add the JTable to a JScrollPane

```
    ArrayList<Product> stock = new ArrayList<Product>(s);

    String[] col = {"Nombre", "Cantidad", "Descripci\u00F3n", "Contenido"};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col,0); 
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    Collections.sort(stock, new Comparator<Product>() {
        public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
            return p1.getNombre().compareTo(p2.getNombre());
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < stock.size(); i++){
        String nombre = stock.get(i).getNombre();
        String cantidad = stock.get(i).getCantidad();
        String descripcion = stock.get(i).getDescripcion();
        String contenido = stock.get(i).getContenido();
        Object[] data = {nombre, cantidad, descripcion, contenido};
        tableModel.addRow(data);
    }

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(width*3/18);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(width/9);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(width*8/18);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(width/9);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, f));
    table.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, f));
    table.setBounds(1, 1, width*8/9, height);
    table.setRowHeight(height/30);
    table.setEnabled(false);

    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer);
    }

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And then through a JButton I modify the contents of the ArrayList, then tell the TableModel that changes have been made and then revalidate() and repaint() the JTable

```
    JButton btnVender = new JButton("Vender");
    btnVender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qué producto quieres vender?");
            int x=1;
            for(Product p : stock){
                if(p.getNombre().equals(n)){
                    x=0;
                    String numero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuántos quieres vender?");
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(numero);
                    p.decrementar(num);
                    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                    table.revalidate();
                    table.repaint();
                    break;                  
                }
            }
            if(x==1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe ese producto");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the JTable won't update but the information does change in the ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for the JTable is not held in the ArrayList but rather resides in the table model itself. Bottom line: don't update the ArrayList but rather the table model itself, here a DefaultTableModel, and your JTable should then display the new data.  Fortunately this should be easy to do as the table model has methods that allow you to extract data with `getValueAt(...)` and update values in its cells with `setValueAt(...)` as well as `addRow(...)` if a new row needs to be added.

Note that if you make changes through the DefaultTableModel, there's no need to directly call `fireTableDataChanged()`, and in fact you shouldn't call this method -- it's the model's responsibility to do so. Likewise there's no need to `revalidate()` or `repaint()` your JTable.

Please check out the [DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for the gory details.

If on the other hand you absolutely need to use the ArrayList as a data nucleus for your JTable, then you shouldn't use a DefaultTableModel but rather create your own TableModel by extending AbstractTableModel and using your ArrayList as its data nucleus. If you do this, then your model's code should take care to call the appropriate `fire...(...)` method after changing the model's state.

Comment: Thank you, I do have to change the values in the ArrayList because the objects inside them are serialized and deserialized, but changing the value from the table with setValueAt() worked.

Comment: @ErickQ: You're welcome, but you're risking danger if you're creating and using parallel collections of data -- both the ArrayList and the TableModel. If this were my problem, I'd create methods to serialize and deserialize my model's data nucleus, which can be obtained via `getDataVector()`, or use the ArrayList as the nucleus of an AbstractTableModel.